# How to properly split logging between requests and responses with Morgan?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, morgan

[Morgan's documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#split--dual-logging) describes that it's possible to split the logging of requests and responses:

> ## split / dual logging
>
> The `morgan` middleware can be used as many times as needed, enabling combinations like:
>
> - Log entry on request and one on response
> - Log all requests to file, but errors to console

In their only related example, there are some comments describing that one middleware will log error responses to console, and another requests to file:

> ```
> // log only 4xx and 5xx responses to console
> app.use(morgan('dev', {
>   skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
> }))
>
> // log all requests to access.log
> app.use(morgan('common', {
>   stream: fs.createWriteStream(path.join(__dirname, 'access.log'), {flags: 'a'})
> }))
> ```

Which seems to achieve the second example of logging all requests to file and errors to console, but not the first one.

I'm a bit lost, I couldn't understand what's telling `morgan` to log only request or only responses. Do I have to concern where to place those middlewares properly?

Currently, I have a single log entry for both request and response, I guess:

```
morgan('[:date[clf]] :remote-addr :url :method HTTP/:http-version :status :remote-user :res[content-length] :referrer :user-agent :response-time ms', {
  stream: {
    write: (message) => {
      winston.silly(message.trim());
    }
  }
});
```

So, how can I properly log *requests* in a `morgan` middleware call, and *responses* in another?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've managed to split Morgan logging between requests and responses with [`immediate`](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#immediate) option:

> #### immediate
>
> Write log line on request instead of response. This means that a requests will be logged even if the server crashes, *but data from the response (like the response code, content length, etc.) cannot be logged.*

So, instead of having this mixed logging:

```
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr :url :method HTTP/:http-version :status :res[content-length] :user-agent :response-time ms', {
  stream: {
    write: (message) => {
      winston.info(message.trim());
    }
  }
}));
```

It's possible to separate them, and log in their correct order:

```
// Logs requests
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr :url :method HTTP/:http-version :user-agent', {
  // https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#immediate
  immediate: true,
  stream: {
    write: (message) => {
      winston.info(message.trim());
    }
  }
}));

// Logs responses
app.use(morgan(':remote-addr :url :method :status :res[content-length] :response-time ms', {
  stream: {
    write: (message) => {
      winston.info(message.trim());
    }
  }
}));
```

---

Note: since [express just enhances Node's own request and response objects](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req), I believe it internally does `res.on('finish', req => { /* log stuff */ })`, when it's not set to `immediate`.